# Create array with single row for keys after iterating arrays in object

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to create a new array if a given element from the columns array is present against the array for each key in fieldValues object.

Looking for ideas to get the output as an expected example from the given structure. Thanks

```
const columns = ['growth item', 'savings item', 'sustainability']

const fieldValues = {
  'additional revenue': [ 'growth item', 'sustainability' ],
  'energy costs': [ 'savings item' ],
  'managing energy': [ 'savings item' ]
}

const categories = [];

const newArray = columns.forEach((element) => {
            Object.values(fieldValues).forEach((value) => {
              let res = value.some(val => val === element);
              
              switch(element){
                case "growth item":
                  categories.push({
                    growth:res
                  })
                  break;
                case "savings item":
                  categories.push({
                    save:res
                  })
                  break;
                case "sustainability":
                  categories.push({
                    sustain:res
                  })
                  break;
              }

        })
      })

console.log(categories);
```

I want to get output like this.

Expected output:

```
[
  { growth: true, save: false, sustain: true },
  { growth: false, save: false, sustain: false },
  { growth: false, save: undefined, sustain: false },
]
```

Actual output.

```
[
  { growth: true },
  { growth: false },
  { growth: false },
  { save: false },
  { save: true },
  { save: true },
  { sustain: true },
  { sustain: false },
  { sustain: false }
]
```

Comment: place the ending '}' for fieldValues.

Comment: Added missing '}' for fieldValues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format it as follows, if the column is not present then `false` will be the value in that case:

```
let columns = ['growth item', 'savings item', 'sustainability']

let fieldValues = {
  'additional revenue': [ 'growth item', 'sustainability' ],
  'energy costs': [ 'savings item' ],
  'managing energy': [ 'savings item' ]
  }
  
let result = Object.values(fieldValues).map((values) => {
   return { 
        growth: values.includes('growth item'),
        save: values.includes('savings item'),
        sustain: values.includes('sustainability')
   }; 
});

console.log(result)
```

```js
let columns = ['growth item', 'savings item', 'sustainability']

let fieldValues = {
  'additional revenue': [ 'growth item', 'sustainability' ],
  'energy costs': [ 'savings item' ],
  'managing energy': [ 'savings item' ]
  }
  
let result = Object.values(fieldValues).map((values) => {
   return { 
        growth: values.includes('growth item'),
        save: values.includes('savings item'),
        sustain: values.includes('sustainability')
   }; 
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Love concise solution, much better than mine

Answer (score 2):

using a reduce function may do the job

```js
const columns = ['growth item', 'savings item', 'sustainability']
const colNames = ['growth', 'save', 'sustain'];

const fieldValues = {
    'additional revenue': ['growth item', 'sustainability'],
    'energy costs': ['savings item'],
    'managing energy': ['savings item']
};

const result = Object.values(fieldValues).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const entry = {};
  
    columns.forEach((col, i) => {
        entry[colNames[i]] = curr.indexOf(col) !== -1;
    });
  
    acc.push(entry);
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop order is wrong in your code and also there is a `}` missing in fiedlValues declaration. Besides that we need to create an object for each item in field value and then push that object inside the categories array. You are pushing into categories item each time the nested loop is running.

```
const columns = ['growth item', 'savings item', 'sustainability']

const fieldValues = {
  'additional revenue': [ 'growth item', 'sustainability' ],
  'energy costs': [ 'savings item' ],
  'managing energy': [ 'savings item' ]
}
const categories = [];

const newArray = Object.values(fieldValues).forEach((value) => {
             let tempObj = {};
             columns.forEach((element) => {
              
              let res = value.some(val => val === element);
              
              switch(element){
                case "growth item":
                  tempObj = {...tempObj, growth: res};
                  break;
                case "savings item":
                  tempObj = {...tempObj, save: res};
                  break;
                case "sustainability":
                  tempObj = {...tempObj, sustain: res};
                  break;
              }
              

        });
        categories.push(tempObj);
      })

console.log(categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved by below solution, have a look into this.

```
   var columns = ['growth item', 'savings item', 'sustainability'];

var fieldValues = {
  'additional revenue': [ 'growth item', 'sustainability' ],
  'energy costs': [ 'savings item' ],
  'managing energy': [ 'savings item' ]
};
var ValueConstants = {
"growth item" :"growth",
"savings item" :"save",
"sustainability":"sustain"
}

var categories = [];

for(let key in fieldValues){
    var obj={};
    for(let col of columns){
            obj[ValueConstants[col]]= fieldValues[key].includes(col);
    }    
    categories.push(obj)
} 
console.log(categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems forEach()'s order is changed.

```js
const columns = ['growth item', 'savings item', 'sustainability']

const fieldValues = {
  'additional revenue': [ 'growth item', 'sustainability' ],
  'energy costs': [ 'savings item' ],
  'managing energy': [ 'savings item' ]
} 
const categories = [];
let subObj = {growth: undefined, save: undefined, sustain: undefined};
const newArray = 
Object.values(fieldValues).forEach((value) => {
        columns.forEach((element) => {            
              let res = value.some(val => val === element);
              
              switch(element){
                case "growth item":
                  subObj.growth = res;
                  break;
                case "savings item":
                subObj.save = res;
                  break;
                case "sustainability":
                subObj.sustain = res;
                  break;
              }      
        })
        categories.push(subObj);
        subObj = {growth: undefined, save: undefined, sustain: undefined};
      })

console.log(categories);
```